# Problems setting up virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, virtual, environment

I'm following a tutorial which seems very comprehensive:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

but receiving an error when trying to load ~/.profile after these changes:

```
# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

The entire output after running

```
source ~/.profile
```

is:

```
pi@SamPi:~ $ source ~/.profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 132, in main
    run_hooks(hook, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 161, in run_hooks
    hook_mgr = ExtensionManager(namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 106, in __init__
    verify_requirements)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 188, in _load_plugins
    for ep in self.list_entry_points():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 177, in list_entry_points
    eps = list(pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(self.namespace))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 521, in iter_entry_points
    entries = dist.get_entry_map(group)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in get_entry_map
    self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2261, in parse_map
    raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

Comment: what is the result of `echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON`?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 2):

"check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed":
So reinstall the virtualenvwrapper. Open e new terminal and start from  this line:

$ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper

Comment: Yes unfortunately I've done this and no help... I have another question but can only post every 90 minutes... could I send to you?

Comment: Of course but click my answer as correct for others

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to python 2. Specifying `pip3` fixed teh issue for me.

`sudo pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`